# What does the modulo plus minus mean?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, terminology

May someone please explain what the notations in the image means?

[image: Modulous notation]

In general, for a modulus $q$, what does the $+$ in here $\bmod^+ q$ indicate? What does the $\pm$ in here $\bmod^\pm q$ mean?

Comment: I don't think this is standard notation. Where did you find it? You should provide a reference. Guessing, it sounds like that defines the range of representatives, in the first line it would be $\{0,\ldots,q-1\}$ and in the second $\{-2^{d-1},\ldots,2^{d-1}-1\}$, but that's just a guess

Comment: It's in the Dilithium, round 3 specification documents.

Answer (score 11):

From the [NIST Post-Quantum Cryptography Round 3](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf) submission for Crystals-Kyber:

> **Modular reductions.** For an even (resp. odd) positive integer α, we define $r' = r\bmod^± α$ to be the unique element  $r'$in the range
> $-\frac{α}{2} < r' \le \frac{α}{2}$
> (resp. $-\frac{α-1}{2} \le r' \le \frac{α-1}{2}$) such that $r' = r\bmod α$. For any positive integer α,
> we define $r' = r\bmod^+ α$ to be the unique element $r'$ in the range
> $0 ≤ r' < α$ such that $r' = r\bmod α$. When the exact representation
> is not important, we simply write $r' = r\bmod α$.

It is probably also available elsewhere, but this was my source.

Comment: I think the proof of Gauss's lemma used in quadratic reciprocity had similar ideas of a "centered" mod p instead of the usual 0 thru p-1.

Comment: I wish this definition had used $r'\equiv r\pmod\alpha$ where there is $r'=r\bmod\alpha$. The former means that $r'-r$ is a multiple of $\alpha$. The later, unless otherwise specified, tends to mean what they write $r'=r\bmod^+\alpha$. See e.g. [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=15).

Comment: Since the OP was asking about Dilithium, I checked and the definition is the same, except they added a sentence "We will sometimes refer to this as a centered reduction modulo α"

Comment: I wish floating-point fmod() operator had been defined in this fashion, rather than as yielding a floating-point remainder in a manner that isn't a modular equivalence class.

Comment: @fgrieu arguably the notation should look something like $r' \stackrel{\operatorname{mod}\alpha}= r$ or perhaps $r' \in \{r|\operatorname{mod}\alpha\}$. I always found it weird to write $r' \equiv r\quad (\operatorname{mod}\alpha)$ because $r' \equiv r$ already looks like a strong equality between $r$ and $r'$, which it is not.